# XPath group all child elements per parent element

Tags: xml, xpath

I have to display all the languages per book. I am confused on how to do this. 
I don't want to display each language as in **/books/book/translation** but I want to group them into each book similar to **/books/book/title** but only the translations must display. So basically I'm grouping each book's translations.

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>Book One</title>
        <translation edition="3">Greek</translation>
        <translation edition="2">Chinese</translation>
        <translation edition="2">French</translation>
        <translation edition="1">Dutch</translation>
   </book>
   <book>
        <title>Book Two</title>
        <translation edition="2">Dutch</translation>
        <translation edition="4">Chinese</translation>
        <translation edition="2">Greek</translation>
        <translation edition="3">Spanish</translation>
    </book>
</books>
```

Thanks, sorry if I got the formatting wrong. 
The Result from the XPath Expression should be two results.
First Result:

```
Greek
Chinese
French
Dutch
```

Second Result:

```
Dutch
Chinese
Greek
Spanish
```

I hope this elaborates some more.

Comment: Something like `<translation edition="1">Greek,Chinese,French,Dutch</translation>`? If you can provide more information including desired result it would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show us a source example as well as the desired output

Comment: Output should be in box one: **Greek, Chinese, French and Dutch** , in box Two it should be **Dutch, Chinese, Greek and Spanish**

Comment: So basically the node translation's text should display for each book node. Hope you understand what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath will give you a sequence of two items, each item will have the translations for each of the books, with the translations separated by commas:

```
for $book in //book
return
    string-join($book/translation, ",")
```

This results in:

Greek,Chinese,French,Dutch
Dutch,Chinese,Greek,Spanish

Is that what you were looking for? If so, once you understand the above XPath, you can actually shorted it to:

```
//book/string-join(translation, ",")
```

Comment: I'll report back this evening when I get home.

Comment: adamretter I tried that using XPath Checker in Firefox and I get a Syntax Error. Basically for every book it should show the languages available. This should be displayed per book, so in XPath Checker when you type in the XPath it should show two results, one for Book One (showing all the languages) and another for Book Two (showing all the languages), however if there is another book then a third result should display for Book Three (showing all the languages). I hope this clears everything and it is not as clear as mud.

Comment: I have been told that I can not do what I want purely in XPath. I would have to do this in XSLT.

Comment: I meant XLS Stylesheet.

Comment: Okay, I thought I knew what you wanted, but I think I am still not understanding you exactly. Certainly XPath is somewhat limited, but you can do grouping using `for` expressions if that is what you are after... if not and you need more power then certainly XSLT or XQuery could be an option

Comment: Hi Adam, I will be using XSLT which will give me the results I'm looking for.